# base points of multiplicity $>1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

Let $S$ be a smooth projective surface (I am mostly intrested in the case when $S$ is a product of curves, say $S=\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ but probably this is not important).

Consider a family of curves $X \subset S \times T$ parametrised by a variety $T$ of dimension 2 (the fibres $X_t$ are distinct). Denote the projection $X \to S\ $ as $p_S$ and $X \to T\ $ as $p_T$. Define a map $\tau: X \to \mathbb{P}TS$ which to every point $x \in X$ associates the projectivisation of the tangent vector of $X_{p_T(x)}$ at $p_S(x)$.

My question is: how can one show that there exists $s \in S$ such that the map $\tau$ is non-constant on $p^{-1}(s)$?

In other words, how can one show that there is a point $s \in S$ such that not all curves passing through it touch each other, but on the contrary, their tangent spaces sweep the tangent space of $S$ at this point?

**update**: Consider the map $\sigma: \mathbb{P}(TX/T) \to \mathbb{P}(TS)$ induced by the projection $p_S: X \to S$. If $\sigma^{-1}(v)$ were finite for some $v \in TS$, then the projection of $v$ to $S$ would be the answer to the question. If the image of the map $\sigma$ is of dimension 3 then almost all fibres are of dimension 0, since $\mathbb{P}(TX/T)$ is of dimension 3. Perhaps one can show that $\mathrm{dim}\ \mathrm{Im}\ \sigma=3$?

Comment: On $S = \mathbb P^1\times \mathbb P^1$ you have $TS=\mathcal O(2,0)\oplus \mathcal O(0,2)$, so $\mathbb PTS$ is not trivial. So I am not sure what examples you have in mind.

Comment: I might be missing something obvious, but can't the structure group of the tangent bundle of a Cartesian square of a curve be reduced to $\mathbb{G}_m$ (we get the cocycle with values in $\mathbb{G}_m$ by putting the respective cocycle for the tangent bundle of the curve on the diagonal of the matrix)? The image in $H^1(S,\mathrm{PGL}_2)$ would then be trivial

Comment: This assumption is not crucial to the statement, so I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I am confused by the statement.  Let $\pi:\mathbb{P}(TS)\to S$ be the projectivized tangent bundle.  Let $i:X\to S$ be an unramified morphism from a smooth curve.  Let $\tau:X\to \mathbb{P}(TS)$ be the canonical lift.  Since $\pi\circ \tau$ equals $i$, which is non-constant, thus also $\tau$ is non-constant.  Are you asking something else?  Are you assuming that $\mathbb{P}(TS)$ is isomorphic to $S\times \mathbb{P}^1$?  Do you really want to consider $\text{pr}_{\mathbb{P}^1}\circ \tau$?

Comment: MO has a glitch in TeX: some of the math expressions tend to overlap with the following text, as you can see at the end of "Denote the projection $X\to S$ as..."  The problem can be fixed by adding extra space "\ " just before the ending dollar sign. Strangely, the glitch occurs in the questions, but not in the comments.

Comment: It looks like that in the case of families that are linear systems of curves on the surface we can ask whether there exists or not a linear system of dimension 2 with a base point of multiplicity at least 2 (nontrivial base point, that is not lying on a fixed component of the system).

Comment: Jason, what I mean is that a point $x \in X$ lies on a curve $X_t$ which is embedded in $S$, so $x$ projects to a point $P$ of $S$. The map $\tau$ associates the projectivisation of the tangent vector to $X_t$ at $P$. It might happen that for a given family, if we consider all curves $X_t$ that pass through a point $P$, the projectivisations of the tangent vector at $P$ might be all the same. The question is how to show that for any family of curves there is a point for which it is not the case.

Comment: N B, that's a good way to put it, yes.

Comment: "If $\sigma ^{-1}(x)$ were finite" -- do you mean actually "of cardinality bigger than 1"?

Comment: N B, no, it's only important that there are finitely many curves passing through a point and with a given tangent at that point.

Comment: I want to try to give an intuitive argument, maybe wrong. Suppose, we have such "everywhere self-tangent" family. If the set-theoretic union of fibers $X_t$ over all $t\in T$ contains an open contractible subset (in euclidean topology) $U$, $U\subset S$ then we can define a holomorphic vector field on $U$ determined by tangent vectors to curves through points (I think it is possible to do so if $U$ is sufficiently small). But then our curves (more precisely, their parts lying in $U$) must be integral curves for this vector field, and thus different fibers (=curves) don't intersect in $U$.

Comment: Now dim T+dim of curve=3>2=dim S.

Comment: N B, yes, you are right, and I thought about it. But don't we have to use some kind of existence and uniqueness result for solutions of an ODE? That would require an analytic setting. I wonder if there is an argument that would not depend on the base field.

Comment: Sure, we need to solve an analytic ODE. I started thinking about it in complex case just because it looks natural. I agree that there may be some pathological situations in general. Perhaps, in nonzero characteristic. On the other hand, if the characteristic is 0 we may be able to embed our field into $\mathbb C$ and consider our objects over complex numbers. Then the question is: does the conjectured "global self-tangency" for the family of curves defined over the initial (smaller) field lift to the same phenomenon over $\mathbb C$? If yes, we can repeat the analytic argument.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, it is probably better to add to the question the requirement that all curves $X_t$ are smooth. It seems you need a Bertini-like theorem (a similar remark by N B). In this case, $X$ and $T$ better to be complete (or even projective). Otherwise, I afraid of that there can exist a counter-example. (Not that I know how to construct it.)

Comment: Please, explain how do you define $\sigma$ in your "update". Is not ${\mathbb P}(TX/T)$ equal to $X$ ?

Comment: Sasha, it is the projectivisation of the relative tangent bundle, i.e. projectivisation the fibrewise kernel of the map induced on the tangent bundles of $X$ and $T$ by the projection $X \to T$. The map $X \to S$ induces a map from the relative tangent bundle to the tangent bundle $TX/T$ of $S$, hence induces a map on projectivisations, this is $\sigma$. And yes, $\mathbb{P}(TX/T)$ is isomorphic to $X$.

Comment: So, you should write $\sigma:{\mathbb P}(TX/T)\to{\mathbb P}TS$, not $\sigma:{\mathbb P}(TX/T)\to TS$ (as it stands), or remove ${\mathbb P}$. (In fact, $\sigma=\tau$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I post an answer to close the issue.

The statement is true in characteristic 0, but not in positive characteristic. Conterexamples in the latter case are easy to come by an $S=\mathbb{A}^1 \times \mathbb{A}^1= \mathbb{A}^2$, say, using curves with projections on one of the $\mathbb{A}^1$ factors everywhere ramified.

In characteristic 0 the argument is as follows, working over $\mathbb C$ (one would have to use formal completions of local rings and formal power series, put on the level of ideas the proof is the same).

So suppose the statement is not true. Then one can find a point $y$ and a neighbourgood $z$ such that for any $z \in U$ and any curve $X_t$ incident to $Q'$ the image of $T_x X_t$ in $T_y S$ depends only on $y$. In other words all curves $X_t$ are integral with respect to a distribution on $S$. But by uniqueness of solutions of ordinary differential equations, there can be at most one integral curve incident to each $z \in U$, which contradicts that dimension of $T$ is 2.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, the statement is not true. Suppose $S$ has a fibration $f:S\rightarrow B$ onto a curve; pick up any curve $C$, and put $T=B\times C$, $X=S\times C$. Embed $X$ in $S\times T$ by $(s,c)\mapsto (s, f(s),c)$. Then given $s\in S$ there is only one curve of the family passing through $s$, hence one tangent direction. You need some hypothesis to avoid this trivial situation.

Comment: yes, the fibres $X_t$ are supposed to be distinct, I have clarified this.

Comment: In your Edit, you do not use that $X$ has dimension $3$. Take $X=S={\mathbb P}^1\times{\mathbb P}^1$ with $T={\mathbb P}^1$, $p_T$ the second projection, and $p_S=1_X$. Then $p'(x)$ is surjective. How does "this mean that $\tau$ is surjective on $p^{-1}(s)$" ?

Comment: You are right, I delete this part.